# How to take a screenshot from Azure Devops macos agent

Tags: macos, azure

I'm running some UI tests on Azure devops and my UI tests, which runs smoothly on Linux agents, are getting stucked on macos (I have tested the code on a macmini, it works perfectly).

I now that my tests start the execution, because I had executed some "Hello World" code without issues, but when it comes to my code, it basically hangs.

How I can debug Azure Devops agents? If I got a screenshot, would be nice

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use screencapture and post to a pastebin service.

Example usages with sprunge, which only accept text, but you can convert images while posting.

> ```
> # server side
> screencapture test.jpg
> uuencode foo.jpg < test.jpg | curl -F 'sprunge=<-' http://sprunge.us
> => http://sprunge.us/example
>
> # client side
> curl http://sprunge.us/example | uuencode
> => foo.jpg
> ```

From my own post: [Sprunge: good utility to copy&paste from remote machines](https://ramonmedeiros.github.io/2019/07/16/sprunge-tutorial.html)